# How do I block a specific JS file on Safari?

Tags: mac, safari, javascript, adblock

I have tried adding the full URL to the JS file on Adblock Filter, but it still loads. Is there anyway that I can block specific JS files? (Or any files, really). I know how to block hosts, but not specific urls/files.

Comment: I just tried adding the full URL of a JS file to Adblock and it blocked the file successfully. Which version of AdBlock are you using? Can you tell us which JS file you are trying to block?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try [JavaScript-Blocker](http://javascript-blocker.toggleable.com/home)?

They claim to block frames, XHRs, embeds, objects, and videos from loading and even images. Probably similar to NoScript in the Mozilla-universe.

Comment: I have had JavaScript-Blocker and there is something seriously wrong with it, it makes my safari crash a lot.